# How to access JavaScript variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

How to access JavaScript variable from one location click event function to another.

I have a variable `imdid`, I wan to access this variable in my different click event, How Can i do that.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    $(".img-upload").click(function(){

        //$("#modal").modal('show');

        var imdid = $(this).attr("imgid");



    });


    $(".img-gallary").click(function(){

        var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");

        alert(imgsrc);

        alert(imdid);

    }); 


});

});
```

Many Thanks

Comment: define variable `imdid` outside event handler. i.e. `var imdid;    $(".img-upload").click(function(){
       imdid = $(this).attr("imgid");
    });`

Comment: By Declaring imdid  globally. just remove var keywork from imdid  it will be declared globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Declaring imdid globally. just remove var keywork from imdid it will be declared globally. in javascript if you declare a variable without var or let keyword its availability become global

```
$(".img-upload").click(function() {

  //$("#modal").modal('show');

  imdid = $(this).attr("imgid");

});


$(".img-gallary").click(function() {

  var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");

  alert(imgsrc);

  alert(imdid);

});
```

Comment: @Sam Withworth try this, hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can assign window variable:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $(".first").click(function(){ 
        //variable test 
        window.test = 10;  
    }); 
    $(".second").click(function(){ 
    console.log(window.test); 
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the nature of [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) in javascript, you have to declare your variable `var imdid;` *outside* of the `.click` event-handlers to be able to access it inside both of them. Try, for example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // Variables declared here will be available in both .click-events
  var imdid;

  $(".img-upload").click(function() {

  }

  $(".img-gallary").click(function(){

  }); 
}
```